# Properties of Finite and Infinite $p$-Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups, infinite-groups

By a $p$-group, we mean a group in which every element has order a power of $p$. It is well known that *finite $p$-group has non-trivial center*. But, an infinite $p$-group may have trivial center.

**Question:** What are the properties of finite $p$-group which does not depend on the *finiteness of the group*? (such as *maximal subgroup is normal; normalizer of a subgroup is larger than subgroup, commutator subgroup is proper, etc.*)

The answer may be long (and even endless), so it will be better only to list the properties, and leave their verifications to the reader.

Comment: None of the properties you listed hold for infinite p-groups.  One group is a counterexample for all: Tarski monster.

Comment: @Steve: well! what is the presentation of this counterexample? (this is not explicitly given on wikipedia).

Comment: The "usual" ones are finitely generated, but not finitely presented.  Their construction is given in Olshanskii's *Geometry of Defining Relations*.  It is an open problem if there exists a finitely presented Tarski monster.

Comment: Tarski Monsters have only been shown to exist for very large p (also, it is misleading to say that there is "one group" - there is a continuum of Tarski monsters!). Perhaps this question could be salvaged for small primes? (For example, 2-groups...[Grigorchuk's group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk%27s_group) seems to have all of the required properties, no?)

Comment: @user1729 Well, the "very large" is not really that large any longer, being on the order of 1000 (I forgot the precise number).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I couldn't remember if they had been greatly reduced or not...anyway, my point was that they don't always exist so what can be said about the primes where they don't exist, such as two or three?